# ngIf array contains index

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-ng-if

I have the following code:

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of serviceList; let i = index;">
       <button *ngIf="currentTools contains i" (click)="processService(item)">
       Run Service</button>
  </li>
```

**Is there any way in Angular 2 to check if an array contains the index of my item?**

I basically only want to show the items when their index number is in an array (currentTools), which is dynamically modified in a different process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of serviceList; let i = index;">
  <button *ngIf="currentTools.indexOf(i)>-1" (click)="processService(item)">
    Run Service
  </button>
</li>
```

Try this

Comment: we need to avoid call functions on data binding in angular templates

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid function call inside a data binding like `*ngIf`. Taking this in to account, you should probably do this

```html
 <li *ngFor="let item of serviceList; let i = index;">
    <ng-container *ngFor=let currentTool of currentTools>
       <button *ngIf="currentTool === i" (click)="processService(item)">
       Run Service</button>
    </ng-container>
  </li>
```

You can get more info about why not tu call function inside data binding here [Don't Use Functions Inside Angular Templates and What to Use Instead](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp)

Also, you can check a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58989829/4098749)