# *ngIf check value in array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

New to Ionic and Angular, but hope someone can help me out.

I have the following data:

```
"messages" : [ 
        {
            "sender" : "24",
            "name" : "James",
            "datetime" : ISODate("2019-11-10T20:42:02.090Z"),
            "message" : "test 1",
            "read" : [ 
                {
                    "uid" : "24",
                    "name" : "James",
                    "datetime" : ISODate("2019-11-10T20:42:02.090Z")
                },
                {
                    "uid" : "45",
                    "name" : "Paul",
                    "datetime" : ISODate("2019-11-13T11:32:45.010Z")
                }
            ]
        }]
```

In ionic, I currently have (data is being passed as 'mailbox' and 'uid' is the id of the user)

```
        <ion-item *ngFor="let message of mailbox">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="['/members/mailbox', message.sid" routerDirection="forward">
                {{ message.name}}
                <br />Posted: {{ message.datetime }}
                <div *ngIf="(message.read[0]['uid'] == uid || message.read[1]['uid'] == uid)">READ</div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-item>
```

What i'm after is a better way to write the ngIf, for instance the messages.read can have multiple rows. Is there a way just to check if the value for uid is found in messages.read? I had a play with the angular filter contains, but had no success.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to leave hard work to .ts file.

You can use something like this;

in your .ts file;

```
validateId(message: Object) {
    return message["read"].find(x => x.uid === uid);
  }
```

and in .html;

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of mailbox">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="['/members/mailbox', message.sid" routerDirection="forward">
                {{ message.name}}
                <br />Posted: {{ message.datetime }}
                <div *ngIf="validateId(message)">READ</div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Was hoping to do it all within the .html file, but will settle for this solution. Cheers

Comment: This approach is not recommended as the function will be executed every time the DOM is updated (which could be on mouse hover, scroll etc.)

Answer (score 1):

That's a javascript question not an Angular question, but to answer your question, you can do

```
*ngIf="message.read.filter(x => x.uid === uid).length > 0"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the following console error.                  Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 31 in [message.read.filter(x => x.uid === uid).length]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
let isUidPresent = messages.read.findIndex(reader => reader.uid === uid) > -1
```

and then on your HTML

```
*ngIf="isUidPresent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create and use a custom pipe with parameters.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'in'
})
export class InPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value, array:any[]) : boolean {
        return array.indexOf(value) != -1;
    }

}

@Pipe({
  name: 'map'
})
export class MapPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], mapFn):array {
    return array.map(filterFn);
  }

}
```

Your *.component.ts:

```
...
_mapFn(read):string{
  return read['uuid'];
}
mapFn = _mapFn.bind(this);
...
```

Your template:

```
<div *ngIf="(message.read[0]['uid'] == uid
<div *ngIf="uuid|in:(message.read|map:mapFn)">...</div>
```

Side note: If you implement it in the template like: `message.read.map((read) => return read['uuid'];).indexOf(uuid) != -1;` then angular will call both functions in every change detection process. That would be very bad and **slow down your application** every time. This is why you need to write pipes. With pipes angular only call the functions when reference of objects (uuid, message.read) change.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to accepted answer, I would avoid calling function in template, since it will be called on each change detection, i.e A LOT, and you have it inside an `ngFor`, so that affects even more. If this is a small set of data and not much else happening in the page, using a function in template is just fine, but I like to avoid it whenever I can :)

If I understand your structure of data correctly, basically there can only be one possible `READ` match in your array/user, since an user cannot mark a message read more than once. If that is the case, therefore you could do a nested `ngFor`, you can mark it with `ng-container` to not actually creating an element in the template unless needed.

So I would suggest the following:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of mailbox">
  <ion-item >
    {{ message.name}}
    <br />Posted: {{ message.datetime }}
    <ng-container *ngFor="let r of message.read">
      <div *ngIf="r.uid === uid">READ</div>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a variable to store value whether the letter is read. Then check whether `uid` is contained in your `mailbox` array:

your.component.ts:

```
isRead = false;
uid;

getEmails() {
    this.webAPI.getEmails().subscribe(s => {
        this.mailbox = s;
        isRead = s.read.some(r => r.uid == uid );
    })

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of mailbox">
     <!-- The code is omitted for the brevity -->
     <div *ngIf="isRead">READ</div>
</ion-item>
```